# Weird aptana highlights. What do they mean?

Tags: aptana

I was wondering what the highlights in the source code meant in aptana. I asked all my friends and none seem to figure it out.

They are shades of gray in front of lines that do not seem to follow any rules. Please note that line 4 is just the line cursor is on.

I have attached a screenshot to exemplify it.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It might be highlighting leading tabs or spaces. Visualising those two differently is very handy in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Window->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Themes`, find the embedded source line, and adjust its background so that it matches the other lines.

Comment: This was weird. embedded source line looked like bright gray (like #DDD) but when I changed it it worked. I think it used some sort of transparency. I would never have figured it out on my own. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, my pleasure :) I had quite a bit of trouble figuring that out too.